# need help to build a codeigniter database query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to make it using codeigniter query_builder function. Not getting Idea, please help.

```
$this->db->query("SELECT city as popularcity FROM(SELECT city,count(city) as
countcity FROM ads LIMIT 0, 6) as t ORDER BY MAX(countcity)");
```

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: I want to get the citycode , which city has got maximum entry

Comment: Mean you have to write query using Codeigniter Active Records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->query("SELECT city as popularcity, countcity 
FROM 
(SELECT city, count(city) as countcity FROM ads GROUP BY city) as t
ORDER BY countcity DESC LIMIT 0, 6");
```

Comment: Hi Julio, Thanks a lot, but how to convert it to query builder (codeigniter) ?

Comment: its right. deleted your alias by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
$this->db->select("city as popularcity, countcity"); 
$this->db->from("(SELECT city, count(city) as countcity FROM ads GROUP BY city) as t");
$this->db->order_by("countcity DESC");
$this->db->limit(0,6);
```